# Are there any non-prefixed classes in the built-in frameworks for iOS and OS X development?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, naming-conventions

Prefixing classes is great when writing frameworks for other people so that you can use multiple frameworks with similarly named classes and not have collisions.

However in an application binary itself, the main application classes don't really need prefixes unless they might collide with some non-prefixed classes in some library, either third-party or built-in.

Obviously third-party libraries can be vetted, but it's hard to look through the entirety of Cocoa.framework and QuartzCore.framework and Foundation.framework and CoreAnimation.framework etc to figure out if there are any non-prefixed classes.

Does anyone know off-hand or know of a way to check, whether there are any non-prefixed classes in any of the built-in libraries? With a definitive answer the general public would feel much more comfortable naming their classes without prefixes in the application binary's main (solitary) codebase.

Thank you.

Comment: If this includes the POSIX APIs as well, then you are sure to have some that aren't prefixed. As far as Quartz & Foundation are concerned, I would assume that all are prefixed.

Comment: Apple is pretty good about following its own rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With a definitive answer the general public would feel much more comfortable naming their classes without prefixes in the application binary's main (solitary) codebase.

The compiler will tell you if your class names conflict at runtime.  This is defined by the headers you include, and the linker path.

There is no need to scan the codebase for non-prefixed classes as you will not be able to compile.

If you have a duplicate class name you will get the error "Duplicate Interface Found for bla bla bla".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are a few legacy classes that don't have prefixes. `Object`, `List`, and `Protocol` come to mind. (Yes, `Protocol` is the name of a class supplied by Apple, and it even inherits from `Object` rather than `NSObject`.)

The headers for those classes are in `/usr/include/objc/`.

Comment: `Class` isn't a class, it's a structure.

Comment: `List` isn't actually used by the modern runtime, so you can use that class name in iOS apps and 64-app Mac apps.

Comment: True, but it *is* there on 32-bit Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the legacy class names mentioned by Jonathan Grynspan, there are definitely unprefixed class names in some private frameworks.  For example, the `MIME` private framework contains classes named `Message`, `MimeBody`, and others.

You can't link directly with a private framework like `MIME` (if you want to be in the App Store).  But you might link with the public `MessageUI` framework, and `MessageUI` links to the private `MIME` framework.  When you launch your app, the Objective-C runtime will notice that there are two classes with the same name, and warn you that it's arbitrarily choosing one of them and ignoring the other.